# jQuery data input validation min and max in option type number

Tags: codeigniter-3

jquery data input validation min and max in number

```
<td align='right'>
  <label for="decimal"> <?php echo form_error('price') ?></label>
    <input style="background-color:#FFFF42" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
</td>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#price').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val() > 20 ){
     alert("Price Max USD. 20");
     $(this).val('20');
   }
   else if {
    ($(this).val() < 5 ){
    alert("Price Min USD. 5");
    $(this).val('5');
}
});
</script>
```

but this doesn't work there is no action

Comment: put your keyup script into jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}), otherwise your script already execute but DOM havent complete load.

Comment: please give an example I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#price').keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val() > 20 ){
         alert("Price Max USD. 20");
         $(this).val('20');
     }
     else if($(this).val() < 5 ){
        alert("Price Min USD. 5");
        $(this).val('5');
     }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td align='right'>
  <label for="decimal"> <?php echo form_error('price') ?></label>
    <input style="background-color:#FFFF42" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="price" value="" />
</td>
```

Comment: how to hidden NaN in form validation?

Comment: NaN? what's that? form validation only validate input controls.

Comment: change NaN to 0, if(isNaN(tal))  var tal = 0;